# Positioning an imageview inside a FrameLayout with layout?! (changing ImageResource)

Tags: android, imageview

I have an ImageView with absolute size and position (in the FrameLayout):

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    layout((int)left, (int)(bottom-width), (int)(left+width), (int)bottom);
}
```

now when I change my ImageResource with:

```
setImageResource(...);
```

the position of all Images is set to top left for one second.. 
and then switches back to normal!

i also use:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    setMeasuredDimension((int)width, (int)width);
}
```

Comment: So everything ends up in the right position, but they just move to the corner and then back when you change the image for one of the elements?

Comment: yes i think setImageResource is drawing the image new and sets the layout new?! - the default position (top left) is shown for just one second,..